# Open terminal in same window (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I've an issue. I want to create a .desktop executable file which will execute a command in the terminal. I used the below code for the same.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=python2 ./main.py
Name=Air Hockey
Comment=This runs Air Hockey in one click
Icon=./logo.png
```

The terminal which opens up with this code has default directory as it's address. I want to launch it in the directory from which this (.desktop) file is executed.

I've tried use %k but it proved to be of no good.

Comment: Why do you care which directory it runs in? If it's important, have the Python script change directories when you start it.

Answer (score 0):

%k return the name of the desktop file with path.

Assume main.py is the name of your script

You can try :

```
Exec=python2 $(dirname %k)/main.py
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This is not working. I feel this is not possible in Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use python at all but you can set the Path in the desktop file.Path=Your directory and Exec=python2 main.py.If you want to keep the terminal open, use python2 -i main.py.

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked with removing the spaces in the name of the directory.

```
Exec=bash -c 'cd $(dirname %k) && python2 main.py'
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47775/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-in-a-desktop-file-to-be-relative-to-the-locat